# Pagination: First request without a cursor in GraphQL?

Tags: swift, graphql, pagination, apollo-client

I think there is something I don't understand here... First time working with cursor-based pagination in GraphQL.

I am using the Apollo iOS client in my swift project.

What I can't seems to grasp is that I have a query that looks like this:

```
query BalloonsList {
  balloons {
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
      startCursor
      endCursor
    }
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        id
        name
        description
        imageUrl
        variant
        color
        price
        availableSince
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works perfectly, the server always responds with 5 objects and I receive the end-cursor for the next request. I can pass in the cursor by implementing a variable in the query like so:

```
query BalloonsList($cursor:String) {
  balloons(after:$cursor) {
```

However, when I have this variable in my query and I don't have a cursor for the very first request it fails of cause. So, an option could be to create two different queries one with the variable and one without for the first request, but it just seems wrong.

I feel like there is something fundamental I don't understand here? How do I implement the `after:` parameter in my query only after my first fetch?

Hope it makes sense

Comment: To me it does not make sense as `cursor` should be an optional variable and you can leave it out (as indicated by the type `String`, while `String!` would be non-optional).

Answer (score 1):

@Herku was right. This:

```
query BalloonsList($cursor:String) {
  balloons(after:$cursor) {
```

This worked since it's optional. What caused the problem was that Apollo had created another type for me called ID instead of String.